# Custom Attribute Validation: make field required based on selected option

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to make a field required, if a specific `option` is selected from a `select`.

What I have so far:

ViewModel:

```
public enum RequestType
{
    PaidLeaveOfAbsence = 1,
    WorkFromHome = 2,
    SickLeave = 3,
    BriefLeaveOfAbsence = 4
}

public class RequestFormViewModel
{
    public RequestType SelectedRequestType { get; set; }

    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    [RequieredIf("SelectedRequestType")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

CustomAttribute:

```
public class RequieredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private readonly string _otherProperty;

    public RequieredIfAttribute(string otherProperty)
    {
        _otherProperty = otherProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string comment = (string)value;

        RequestType selectedRequestType = (RequestType)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_otherProperty).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment) && selectedRequestType == RequestType.BriefLeaveOfAbsence)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Comment is requiered.");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-required-if", "Comment is requiered.");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-other", "#" + _otherProperty);
    }

    private static bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }
        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-0 col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SelectedRequestType" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="SelectedRequestType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<RequestType>()" class="form-control">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Select a request</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="SelectedRequestType" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FromDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FromDate" class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="fromDate" autocomplete="off" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FromDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ToDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ToDate" class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="toDate" autocomplete="off" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ToDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Comment" class="control-label">Comment</label>
        <textarea asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-0 col-md-2"></div>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" id="SelectedRequestType" name="SelectedRequestType">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select a request</option>
    <option value="1">PaidLeaveOfAbsence</option>
    <option value="2">WorkFromHom</option>
    <option value="3">SickLeave</option>
    <option value="4">BriefLeaveOfAbsence</option>
</select>
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="Comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" data-val="true" data-val-other="#SelectedRequestType" data-val-required-if="Comment is required." name="Comment"></textarea>
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Comment" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

The server side validation works fine. I'm stuck on adding client side validation, so far I have this:

validator.js

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("required-if",
    function (value, element, param) {
        var otherProp = $($(element).data('val-other'));
        console.log(otherProp);
        if (!value.trim() && otherProp.val() == 4) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
)

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("required-if", ["other"], 
    function (options) {
        console.log(options);
        options.rules["required-if"] = "#" + options.params.other;
        options.messages["required-if"] = options.message;
});
```

I've put some `console.log()`s but they are never executed. (I did preserve the log in chrome).

Most of the google searches are from the ASP.NET MVC that implement `IClientValidatable` interface and are not very useful. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2.0.

I did read the microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iclientmodelvalidator) and the [link](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) they provided on custom adapters for unusual validators.

Questions:

1. How can I achieve the expected behavior this way? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
2. What are my other options? Should I just make a separate client side validation with the jQuery Validation Plugin? I don't like the idea of 2 separate places for validation.
3. Can someone explain to me why the `console.log()`s inside the javascript functions are never executed? I have custom validators for `FromDate` and `ToDate` and they are executed there. The only difference is that I use 
   `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool` instead of `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `comment` section was outside the `form`, so the validation would never happen.
The answer was found in the [link](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) from my original post.

> Important note: jQuery Validate requires your input elements to be
>   inside of a `<form>` element in order to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your FormViewModel extend IValidatableObject. Once you do that implement Validate method. There you can have custom validation based on values in your Model. Something like:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(SelectedRequestType == RequestType.PaidLeaveOfAbsence) 
        {
            // Check if field is not null and return
            yield return new ValidationResult(
            "SomeField should be present.",
            new[] { "SomeField" });
        }
    }
```

You can make above syntax more elegant with use of [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

You can find more about model validation at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant for client side validation. Could you elaborate?
And as I mentioned in my post, I've already read the microsoft docs (the link you're providing).